# Fiddler - asp.net web api custom POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I have a Backbone.js application and it's calling one of my WEB API custom POST method. Here is the code to  my Custom POST

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
            (
                name: "UserAdministrationApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/PostUserInfo/{EmployeeDTO}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    EmployeeDTO = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    controller = "UserAdministration",
                    action = "PostUserInfo",
                });
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("PostUserInfo")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostUserInfo(EmployeeDTO value)
        {
            // handling POST
        }
```

EmployeeDTO

```
   public class EmployeeDTO
   {
    public bool masAccess { get; set; }
    public bool reportAccess { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string office { get; set; }
   }
```

When I try to test this in Fiddler even before going to test it with Backbone.js code, I am getting 500 Internal error. Not sure what's wrong

// FIDDLER TEST

```
POST : http://localhost:56501/api/useradministration/PostUserInfo



Request Body

  {
     masAccess:"true"
     reportAccess:"false"
   }
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: What is the request you are using to test this? Also code inside `PostUserInfo` might be relevant.

Comment: value parameter itself is getting set to null.

Comment: Is this exactly how you test it with fiddler? Since by default fiddler expects body in form of query string: `masAccess=true&reportAccess=false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

The EmployeeDTO should not be part of the routeTemplate, as Andrei mentioned.

Your request body is not valid JSON according to JSONlint.com. Try

```
{
  "masAccess": "true",
  "reportAccess": "false"
}
```

Also, you may need to add the header `Content-Type: application/json` to your Fiddler request.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the EmployeeDTO in the router config. I just had to set Content-Type: application/json in the header. Thanks man. It's a very simple thing and I missed that.

Comment: Yeah... I was also missing `Content-Type: application/json`. Thanks for the heads up! :)